# Greensock Tweenlite transformations

Tags: css, svg, gsap

I'm using tweenlite library to rotate, move and zoom image.
The problem is, that I get 3D transformations on image, 
but I would like to have 2D transformations.
If tweenlite detects that there is browser which doesn't support 3D, he will do 2d. How can I force him to always do 2D? It must be some setting. Or just disable 3D. (3d inside svg doesn't work in any IE browser)

This is ok:

```
transform="matrix(0.1082 0 0 0.1082 97 58)"
```

This is what I don't wont to have:

transform: matrix3d(0.1082, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1082, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 53.5881, 48.8135, 0, 1);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is called **[`force3D`](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/Plugins/CSSPlugin/)**. Navigate to this link I shared and look for section named **force3D** on this page.

Currently, **`force3D`** defaults to a value of `auto` which means it will automatically decide when to use `transform3d` and when not to.

Also, there is a way to set it globally instead of appending it into every tween:

```
CSSPlugin.defaultForce3D = false;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, I don't have such option.
And if I inspect CSSPlugin, I have only: defaultSkewType, defaultSmoothOrigin, defaultTransformPerspective.

Comment: can you try adding `force3D: false` into your tweens first. How does your code look like right now? Can you edit your question and add your JS code please?